# Does AWS Direct Connect require a physical network connection?

Tags: networking, router, amazon-web-services

I am working on a project that is planning to use AWS Direct Connect to exchange files with our partners. I am new to AWS Direct Connect and while I am not a network expert, I understand how internet/networks work.

I am trying to estimate costs etc... So i have the following questions?

1) I have a On premise Data Center. Do I need to have a physical network connection (meaning a network cable going out of our router) between my DC and AWS DC, in addition to the standard internet connection?

2) Is it simpler/cheaper to use AWS Direct Connect when both the partner and our systems are in AWS Cloud (i believe they have to be in the same region).

3) How does AWS Direct Connect actually work? This is my understanding, please confirm or correct. Once a direct network connection has been established between our systems and the partner's, then the two systems are just like any any 2 systems on the network, we can exchange files between them by simple sharing of folders.(SAMBA etc...)

Any clarity will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

(1). Yes, although the "network cable" would likely take the form of a private leased circuit you would purchase from a telecommunications provider.

Direct Connect is a service that allows you to establish  connections between your network and the AWS network at [selected physical locations](https://aws.amazon.com/directconnect/features/).  If you do not have equipment at any of these locations, you will need to lease a transport circuit from a telecommunications company to bring the Direct Connect circuit the rest of the way to your data center... or purchase your Direct Connect circuit from such a provider rather than directly from AWS (required for port speeds under 1GB -- you have no option but to purchase your Direct Connect through a partner).

(2). No, because Direct Connect isn't designed to connect you to other companies.  If I have a Direct Connect connection and you also have a Direct Connect connection, this doesn't allow us to communicate with each other, nor would we want to, because there are charges per gigabyte on Direct Connect.

Direct Connect is designed to allow you to access your VPCs (which you would normally access via VPN or the Internet) and/or other AWS Services that you would normally access via the Internet -- such as Amazon S3 -- via your own dedicated connection.  From a cost perspective, you pay less per gigabyte but you also pay monthly fixed charges to AWS and/or a partner company for the port charge and any transport.

(3). As noted above, if you want to connect to another company's network, you either need a VPN over the Internet or a leased private circuit from a telecommunications provider, connecting your network to theirs, with appropriate firewalls and address space coordination.

Sharing of files across connected networks using Samba is probably a rarely-used configuration, and is unlikely to work well at all.  The SMB protocol is not well-suited to WAN applications.

Comment: This should have been the accepted answer. This helped me with my research. Thanks